# Using Groovy JsonSlurper with Reader in Jenkins causing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: groovy, jenkins, illegalargumentexception, reader, jsonslurper

I have the following code that I'm executing from a Jenkins non-System Groovy Script using Groovy 2.4.3

```
private void readJsonFile() {
    if (testsValid == false) {
        def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
        try {                   
            println "FileReader("+jsonFileName+")"
            def fr = new FileReader(jsonFileName)
            println "About to slurp from FileReader "+fr
            println "Class: " + fr.getClass()
            tests = jsonSlurper.parse(fr)
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            println "Properties File Not Found: "+jsonFileName
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            println "Illegal Argument: " + e.getCause()
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

But, when I run it I get the following exception:

```
FileReader(/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/2TierUtmsLog2/resources/utmsdata.json)
About to slurp from FileReader java.io.FileReader@125d92c
Class: class java.io.FileReader
Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at JenkinsJsonTestDao.readJsonFile(JenkinsJsonTestDao.groovy:82)
    at JenkinsJsonTestDao.readJenkinsUtmsTest(JenkinsJsonTestDao.groovy:51)
    at JenkinsTestDaoIf$readJenkinsUtmsTest.call(Unknown Source)
    at JenkinsTestLogger.logTestResult(JenkinsTestLogger.groovy:32)
    at JenkinsTestLoggerIf$logTestResult.call(Unknown Source)
    at JenkinsLog.logTest(JenkinsLog.groovy:76)
    at JenkinsLog$logTest.call(Unknown Source)
    at JenkinsLog.main(JenkinsLog.groovy:44)
Build step 'Execute Groovy script' marked build as failure
```

The JsonSlurper.parse(Reader r) method does take a Reader, so I don't understand why this isn't working.  I've also tried using the JsonSlurper.parse(String s) method, but get the same error.  I've also printed out the contents that is read via the FileReader and it's correct.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or is this another Jenkins restriction I'm running up against.

Added requested info:

`jsonSlurper: groovy.json.JsonSlurper@19e733e
Print of new File(...)
{ "job": [
    {
    "jenkins_name": "ForceAResult-fail",
    "utmsEnabled": "1",
    "utmsCycleId": "1",
    "utmsProejct": "Unity",
    "utmsTeam": "CA-SS System Software",
    "utmsTestName": "Force_a_test",
    "utmsTestPlanId": "2",
    "utmsTestSetId": "3",
    },
    {
    "jenkins_name": "ForceAResult-pass",
    "utmsEnabled": "1",
    "utmsCycleId": "1",
    "utmsProejct": "Unity",
    "utmsTeam": "CA-SS System Software",
    "utmsTestName": "Force_a_test",
    "utmsTestPlanId": "2",
    "utmsTestSetId": "3",
    }
]}`

Uncaught Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:92)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.setProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:2699)

**Added info for Divesh**

[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Groovy Version
System Groovy Version: 1.8.9
PATH: /var/lib/ccache/bin:/c4shares/auto/tools/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/accurev/bin:/opt/CmTools/shbin:/re/bin:/re/thirdparty_tools/java/tags/linux/Production/bin:/opt/pegasus/bin:/re/thirdparty_tools/ant/tags/Production/bin:/c4shares/auto/devutils/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/usr/NX/bin

GROOVY_HOME: null

[Groovy Version] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation/Groovy_2.4.3/bin/groovy "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Groovy Version/hudson6179818785298037506.groovy"
Sep 24, 2015 8:11:25 AM org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.m12n.MetaInfExtensionModule newModule
WARNING: Module [groovy-nio] - Unable to load extension class [org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NioGroovyMethods]
Execute Groovy script - non-System

Start of Divesh's Request:

```
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(byte[])
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(char[])
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.io.File)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.io.InputStream)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.io.Reader)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.net.URL)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(byte[],java.lang.String)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.io.File,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.io.InputStream,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.net.URL,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.net.URL,java.util.Map)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.util.Map,java.net.URL)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.net.URL,java.util.Map,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse(java.util.Map,java.net.URL,java.lang.String)
public java.lang.Object groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parseText(java.lang.String)Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Can you print out `jsonSlurper` and check `new File(jsonFileName).text` looks OK?

Comment: You're also never closing your reader.  Try `new File(jsonFileName).withReader { fr -> ... Code... }`

Comment: The catch block for `IllegalArgumentException` prints "Illegal Argument:", but I do not see this string in your output. Typo?

Comment: Tim, I added the two print statements you requested.  I've pasted the output below.  Also, that's a good point about closing the reader.  I'll be sure to add that in

Divesh, I noticed that the "Illegal Argument" was not being printed out.  I added a catch-all exception.  The results are below too.

Comment: `jsonSlurper: groovy.json.JsonSlurper@19e733e
Print of new File(...)
{ "job": [
    {
    "jenkins_name": "ForceAResult-fail",
    ....
    },
    {
    "jenkins_name": "ForceAResult-pass",
    ....
    }
]}

Uncaught Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: 
....`

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting.  I can't figure out how to get it right.

Comment: Add it to the question, it always looks rubbish in comments

Comment: Added requested info to the question

Comment: This is indeed weird; I can get your script to run on my machine. Could you run the following script (on the Jenkins box facing the problem) -
`groovy -e "print (new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().getMetaClass().getMethods()*.toString().findAll{it ==~ /.*parse.*/}.join('\n'))"`

Comment: I'm trying to check if your Jenkins box is using the correct Groovy version and that the version of JsonSlurper being used indeed has a parse() method that takes a Reader as an argument.

Comment: I had to run it in a non-System Groovy script in the Jenkins job, since that's the only way to use the version of Groovy that I'm specifying.  I also added information to printout the Groovy environment for both System and non-System Groovy Scripts

Comment: Just to be sure there wasn't a difference from running it in a jenkins groovy script file versus running it in a jenkins Groovy command, I created a script file with the getMetaClass() query.  The results were the same.  Both contained the Reader version of JsonSlurper.parse()

Comment: I took the code I was using and cut it down to just the JsonSlurper call that I was making and put it into a groovy script.  This time it worked.  So it's probably related to the class infrastructure I'm trying to run in the groovy script file.  I'll continue investigating.  When I find the answer I'll post it here.